# insert into xml postgres c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

I'm having difficulty executing an insert query from c# to postgres. I use both dapper and npgsql.

The method I use is this:

```
public void InsertQuery(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        var query = "INSERT INTO cars(name, price, xml_file) VALUES(@name, @price, @xmlDoc)";

        DynamicParameters dynamicParams = new DynamicParameters();
        dynamicParams.Add("@name", "pegot2", DbType.AnsiString, ParameterDirection.Input, 255);
        dynamicParams.Add("@price", 15000);
        dynamicParams.Add("@xmlDoc", xmlDoc, DbType.Xml,ParameterDirection.Input);

        try
        {
            int res = Connection.Execute(query, dynamicParams);
            if (res > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("row inserted");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught exception:\n" + e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The table I use looks like this:

[image]

When I try to execute the query I get this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Can't write CLR type System.Xml.XmlDocument with handler type TextHandler'
```

I'm pretty sure I messed up the syntax somewhere. Any help is welcome!

Comment: I'm not familiar with working with xml in postgres, but I would not expect it to know how to work with a .NET type like XmlDocument. You probably need to get its OuterXml property and put that in the database

Comment: I think I fixed it. I used

        public string GetXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
        {

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            myxml.WriteTo(tx);

            return sw.ToString();
        }
To get the correct string. string.OuterXml also seems to work fine. However the string generated from xml does not include the line: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"

Do you think this could be a problem?

Comment: I can't say if that will be a problem, it depends on whatever will be consuming the xml.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to my answer, however both skip the line:

```
//<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

public void InsertQuery(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO cars(name, price, xml_file) VALUES(@name, @price, @xmlDoc)";

    DynamicParameters dynamicParams = new DynamicParameters();
    dynamicParams.Add("@name", "pegot2", DbType.AnsiString, ParameterDirection.Input, 255);
    dynamicParams.Add("@price", 15000);

    //can use xmlDoc.OuterXml too
    dynamicParams.Add("@xmlDoc", XmlToString(xmlDoc), DbType.Xml,ParameterDirection.Input);

    try
    {
        int res = Connection.Execute(query, dynamicParams);
        if (res > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("row inserted");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught exception:\n" + e);
        throw;
    }
}

    //.OuterXml also seems to work
    public string XmlToString(XmlDocument myxml)
    {

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        myxml.WriteTo(tx);

        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

@Michael Effraimidis: Your answer is fine. If you need the xml declaration you can do this:

```cs
public string XmlToString(XmlDocument myxml)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = false };
    var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
    myxml.Save(xmlWriter);
    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

Other properties are also controlable through the XmlWriterSettings. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings?view=net-5.0).